# How to detect multiple resolutions images from a single drawable folder at android studio

Tags: android-layout, android-studio, android, android-drawable

Iam developing an **Android app** using **Android Studio**, I referred this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24349917/do-we-need-to-add-all-images-with-different-dpi-to-android-apps) to use different images resources but i failed to get the output.

What i need is "I have *480x640_240dpi, 480x800_240dpi, 480x854_240dpi*, 600x1024_240dpi in my **drawable-hdpi** folder", but while running the app the images are stretching.

How to detect the **correct resolution image** to the **corresponding device**.
And also help me how to add images to the tablet (that too only in landscape mode, in my app tablet wont work on portrait as requirements).
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: i need to target extact device to its exact resolution how its possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Targeting specific resolutions is possible with resource directory qualifiers. For example you can create folder `drawable-w320dp-h533dp-hdpi` for 480px x 800px image on `hdpi` screen.

EDIT: Since you probably are using Android Studio, you can define the qualifiers in the dialog when you are creating new resource directory.

Comment: Super, answered what i need. tank u

Comment: But one think is how i have to give the images in landscape mode(folder name?)

Comment: Switch width and height :)

Answer (score 1):

Put your all images according to the resolutions.
i.e

- > res/drawable-mdpi/graphic.png         // bitmap for medium-density
  >   res/drawable-hdpi/graphic.png         // bitmap for high-density
  >   res/drawable-xhdpi/graphic.png        // bitmap for
  >   extra-high-density res/drawable-xxhdpi/graphic.png       // bitmap
  >   for extra-extra-high-density

for more detail 
http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Comment: yeah i know this but i need to target extact device to its exact resolution how its possible?